# UPDATE entre 2 tabelas no SQL dando erro

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Estou tentando realizar um UPDATE e ele me traz o seguinte erro: 
"Mensagem 157, Nível 15, Estado 1, Linha 40 - An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement."

Segue o código do UPDATE:

```
 UPDATE Venda_Cartao SET 
 Venda_Cartao.ID_Caixa = (SELECT distinct ID_Caixa FROM Caixa_Movimentacao a
 where a.ID_Forma_Pagamento = 3 and a.Valor = convert(decimal(18,2),                 
 convert(decimal(18,2),SUM(vc.Valor_Pago))) and DAY(Data_Movimentacao) =
 DAY(vc.Data) and MONTH(Data_Movimentacao) = MONTH(vc.Data) and
 YEAR(Data_Movimentacao) = YEAR(vc.Data)) from Venda_Cartao vc 
 where vc.ID_Caixa is null
```

Comment: O issue encontra-se respondido neste [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25937315/sql-update-query-an-aggregate-may-not-appear-in-the-set-list-of-an-update-stat). A sintaxe não favorece o objetivo do script.
Obrigado.

Comment: Explique o que a consulta deve realizar, tabelas envolvidas etc para que seja possível postar sugestões.